# Как вызвать функцию в динамически созданном скрипте?

Tags: javascript, scripts

Есть скрипт №1 который создает элемент - скрипт №2 и инжектит его в документ.
Как в первом скрипте вызвать функцию из второго скрипта?

```
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('injected.js'),
function(data) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.innerHTML = data;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[3].setAttribute("onLoad", "injected();");
    
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage)
    function gotMessage (message, sender, sendResponse) {
        //ВОТ ТУТ НАДО ВЫЗВАТЬ ФУНКЦИЮ ИЗ ВТОРОГО СКРИПТА
    }
});
```

Причем строчка ниже отрабатывает

```
document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[3].setAttribute("onLoad", "injected();");
```

как сделать вызов функции не только после onLoad?

UPDATE 2

```
$.getScript(chrome.extension.getURL('injected.js'), function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    console.log(data, textStatus, jqxhr) //undefined "success" {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ,setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
    injected(); //Error in event handler: ReferenceError: injected is not defined
});
```

Получается что скрипт создается (после инжекта вызываются методы, логи) но в getScript() data == undefined. Ну и injected(); не находит

Comment: а просто так вызвать нельзя?

Comment: Что происходит когда просто пишете `injected()` ?

Comment: ReferenceError: injected is not defined  at gotMessage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас уже есть JQuery судя по коду, то используйте [getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/). Загруженный таким образом скрипт будет выполнен в глобальном контексте, и затем будет вызвана ваша callback-функция.

Смотрите пример, в котором загружается плагин для анимирования цветов, а затем запускается анимация посредством этого плагина:

```js
$.getScript("https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

  //ВОТ ТУТ МОЖНО ВЫЗВАТЬ ФУНКЦИЮ ИЗ ВТОРОГО СКРИПТА
  $("#block").animate({ backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0)" }, 5000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

<div id="block">Hello World!</div>
```

В вашем случае:

```
$.getScript(chrome.extension.getURL('injected.js'), function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
  injected();
});
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос, вставил код как я понял, но слетела кодировка и ошибка ReferenceError: injected is not defined

Comment: Зачем вы создаете скрипт вручную, если getScript уже делает всю работу за вас? Внимательно почитайте про getScript.

Comment: обновил ответ, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: так все таки inject() или injected()? и там вообще эта функция имеется? может проблема в скрипте?

Comment: есть, я менял название, ну и пробовал другие функции, не видит их.

Comment: Если поверить, что там все в порядке, то без полного кода я не знаю, что у вас там не работает, и почему "injected is not defined". Скрипт загружен и размещен, а почему нет функции - это уже другой вопрос, на который ответить невозможно по доступной информации.

Comment: Этот вопрос закрыл, создал новый, с полным кодом

Comment: еще вопрос в догонку, если я вставляю скрипт вот так document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script); то его видно в странице, а если таким способом как вы указали, его где-то видно?

Comment: jQuery в таком случае создает временный тег <script> и эвалуирует в нем код полученный через ajax `jQuery.globalEval(data);`. В самой странице он не виден. Исходник: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/ajax/script.js

Comment: Понял, спасибо, одно но, почему при таком инжекте слетает кодировка? Русские  символы не читабельны. Как это исправить?

Comment: charset страницы и подгружаемого скрипта должен совпадать из-за той-самой особенности размещения скрипта.